# Post processing in Spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Support for post processing has been introduced in Spring Cloud Stream https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_post_processing_after_sending_message.

The post processing method is invoked in both publish success and publish failure. Is there an option to find out whether publish was successful or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but don't confuse post-processing with error handling for which there is a separate mechanism - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling
While it is similar to the post processor that you have mentioned, there are some idiomatic differences.
Please give it a go and let us know if you still have questions

Comment: Hi Oleg Zhurakousky, i am working on a use case where after successful publish, an operation has to be performed. How to achieve this in spring cloud stream?

Comment: PostProcessingFunction is NOT invoked on failure. What makes you think that it does? If there is a condition when it does get invoked it is probably a bug, but i can't reproduce it, so please let me know